# Split a tmux window into panes, with one or more panes in a separate terminal window

Tags: tmux

I know that I can have two different views on the same session [using commands described in this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282365/using-multiple-terminal-x-windows-with-one-tmux-session).

This is how that would look:

```
    monitorA                          monitorB
    ┌─────────────────────────────┐  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐                       
    │                             │  │                                                │                       
    │ ┌─────┐   ┌─────┐   ┌─────┐ │  │ ┌────────────┐ ┌────────────┐ ┌────────────┐   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │    P1      │ │     P2     │ │     P3     │   │                       
    │ │ P1  │   │  P2 │   │ P3  │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │ └────────────┘ └────────────┘ └────────────┘   │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │                                                │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  │  session1                      window1         │                       
    │ │     │   │     │   │     │ │  └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘                       
    │ └─────┘   └─────┘   └─────┘ │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │                             │                                                                           
    │  session1         window1   │                                                                           
    └─────────────────────────────┘
```

And, thanks to @Spikey8D, I know that I can create a new session and then link a window in that new session to an existing window like so:
`<prefix>:link-window -s <session-name>:<window-number>`

But what I want is shown below: a pane (or panes) of the same window in a second terminal. Please imagine/assume that both terminal windows are "full screen" and fill each monitor, A and B.

```
     monitorA                         monitorB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     ┌─────────────────────────────┐  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐                      
     │                             │  │                                                │                      
     │                             │  │ ┌────────────┐ ┌────────────┐ ┌────────────┐   │                      
     │    ┌────────────────────┐   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │     P1     │ │    P2      │ │     P3     │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │       P0           │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ │            │ │            │ │            │   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │ └────────────┘ └────────────┘ └────────────┘   │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │                                                │                      
     │    │                    │   │  │  session1                      window1         │                      
     │    │                    │   │  └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘                      
     │    │                    │   │                                                                          
     │    |                    |   |
     |    |                    |   |
     |    |                    |   |
     │    |                    |   |
     |    |                    |   |
     |    |                    |   |
     |    |                    |   |                                                                      
     |    |                    |   |
     |    |                    |   |                                                                          
     │    └────────────────────┘   │                                                                          
     │  session1         window1   │                                                                          
     └─────────────────────────────┘
```

To further clarify, P0...P3 are labels for the window panes. I've not drawn them as contiguous (as they would be with `C-b %` or `C-b "` because I thought that might be more confusing).

Elaborating further (prompted by @svin83's question), I don't want to create another window on the same session for the following reasons:

- the second monitor (in portrait mode) would only then be available to that window--were it a supplemental pane it could be used in any window of the session.
- were I to proceed to create a second window for each existing window on the main monitor, I'd double the number of windows I have and I dislike having to specify window indices above 9 (because it means typing `C-b "` and selecting an index from a list.

Comment: Why would you need session 1:window 1 to show different panes in one view than the other view? Is there a specific reason for not using another window in session 1?

Comment: @svin83 that's a good question. If I create another window, it shows up in both terminals; if I'm able to create a pane, the pane will not be accessible outside of that window. I do not want another view on a set of existing panes in an existing window. I do not want to increase the number of windows I have open in any given session.

Comment: Then how do you feel about one session per terminal? Panes within one session won't affect other sessions.   

Split views within each session with `Ctrl+b "` or `Ctrl+b %`   
Move to next/previous session with `Ctrl+b (` or  `Ctrl+b )`    

Detach from current session with `Ctrl+b d`    

Detaching leaves your session running in the background, ends tmux, and drops you back to your default shell.  

To start tmux and attach to your last session, instead of creating a new one, use `tmux a`   

You'd still be able to attach both terminals to one session if you wanted to.